# Getting element to along next to eachother

Tags: html, css

Please look at my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9abmoasw/1/).

As you can see I have some HTML elements that I need to sit side by side. The first example is my code, the second is how I want it to look and the 3rd is an example of how I could fix it but is not an option.

I **cannot** change my code from the following structure:

```
<div class="big">1</div>
<div class="big">2</div>
<div class="big">3</div>
<div class="big">4</div>
<div class="small">5</div>
<div class="small">6</div>
<div class="small">7</div>
```

What I need is for the elements to correctly sit side by side, 1 next to 5, 2 next to 6 and 3 next to 7.

I **don't** want to use absolute positioning.

If anyone can help me solve this that would be brilliant!

please remember that I cannot change my HTML, this has to be a CSS solution if at all possible.

Cheers,
Luke.

Comment: Not exactly sure why I have got a down vote here, my question is well structured and I have given code examples...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the CSS for .big too:

```
.big {
    width: 55%;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9abmoasw/2/

Comment: Well you have made me look like a right fool! Such a simple solution, nice one thanks mate. Dam Mondays!